# How to add last logged in and last order date information to customer grid?

Tags: magento2.2.6, customer-grid

Using Magento ver. 2.2.6, how can I add new columns to customer grid showing the last logged-in activity and Last order date?

Comment: did it work for you?

Comment: @Chris Oliver I have the same error when I do a search by keyword on customer grid !? Search by filters works as expected.

Comment: Any solution for this for M2.4.6.
Filtering admin grid make error.

Answer (score 1):

I created extension

https://github.com/DominicWatts/CustomerInfo

But in summary

`view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="customer_columns" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
        <column name="last_login_at">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Last Logged In</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1000</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="order_created_at">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Last Order At</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1000</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

`Model/ResourceModel/Grid/Collection.php`

```php
<?php
namespace Xigen\CustomerInfo\Model\ResourceModel\Grid;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult;
/**
 * Class Collection
 * @package Xigen\CustomerInfo\Model\ResourceModel\Grid
 */
class Collection extends SearchResult
{
    /**
     * Init collection select
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _initSelect()
    {
        parent::_initSelect();
        $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
            ['customer_log' => $this->getTable('customer_log')],
            'customer_log.customer_id = main_table.entity_id',
            ['last_login_at']
        )->joinLeft(
            ['sales_order_grid' => $this->getTable('sales_order_grid')],
            'sales_order_grid.customer_id = customer_log.customer_id',
            ['max(sales_order_grid.created_at) as order_created_at']
        )
        ->group('main_table.entity_id');
        $this->addFilterToMap('customer_id', 'customer_log.customer_id');
        $this->addFilterToMap('created_at', 'main_table.created_at');
        // echo (string) $this->getSelect();
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this extension no longer works. 
Gives the error "Something went wrong with processing the default view and we have restored the filter to its original state" when installed on Order grid.
Would love to see it fixed.